# OpenGL Y420 Shaders

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, jogl

I am working on OpenGL shaders. My current shaders will take textures in RGB24 format and display. I wanted to take Y420 as input and convert into RGB24 at fragment shader level. Guide me to proceed further with this.

Answer (score 0):

The capability to render YUV via OpenGL depends on the platform. Most of the platforms expose YUV streaming texture capability via extensions, for example `GL_OES_EGL_image_external` at http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt

For eglImage based streaming, you can refer to TEST16 in sgxperf codebase at,

https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_gles20_vg.cpp

Additionally, when you use these extensions, it is NOT necessary to do any conversions in the shader. The sampler (HW) already does the conversion to RGB before you process it in the shader.

For developing a complete application though, you typically need other additional mechanisms like synchronisation with the display etc. If your vendor provides a gstreamer sink that integrates GL streaming functionality, that would be the best option.